Variational description of modified Einstein equations
Let us suppose that we have an Einstein equation of the form
$$ R_{(\mu \nu)}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} R=8\pi T_{\mu \nu},$$
where $R$ is an affine connection, which differs from the Levi-Civita connection. Say, for a certain choice of non-metricity and torsion, concretely, we can write this equation as
\begin{equation} \label{this}\overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} \overset{\circ}{R}+ g_{\mu \nu}\left(c_1\overset{\circ}{\nabla}_{\alpha} \psi^{\alpha}+c_2 \psi_\alpha \psi^\alpha \right) + c_3 \left( \overset{\circ}{\nabla}_{\mu} \psi_\nu + \overset{\circ}{\nabla}_\nu \psi_\mu \right) +c_4 \psi_\mu \psi_\nu=8\pi T_{\mu \nu},\end{equation}
where $\circ$ denotes the Levi-Civita connection, and $\psi^{\mu}$ is a four-vector, which fully characterizes the connection $\nabla$, i.e. $\nabla=\overset{\circ}{\nabla}+$ some distortion tensor, which is fully described by the metric and $\psi^{\mu}$. Concretely, this means that
$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \rho}=\overset{\circ}{\Gamma}^{\mu}_{\nu \rho}+d_1 g_{\nu \rho} \psi^{\mu}+d_2 \psi_{(\nu} \delta^\mu_{\rho)} +d_3 \psi_{[\rho} \delta^\mu_{\nu]}$$
Is there a way to derive the proposed field equation \eqref{this}  from a variational principle in either:

Metric formalism, i.e. we fix the connection $\nabla$, which has non-metricity and torsion, which are vectorial(determined by a vector $\psi^\mu$) by $d_1,d_2,d_3$? Not necessarily $f(R)=R$ action, we can add higher invariants if it helps.

Palatini formalism, i.e. we write some action, which upon variation of connection fixes the connection, then the metric variation yields the above equations? (Perhaps by coupling to geometry the matter sector)


Altogether, is there any variational principle, which could lead to the field equation written above?
